# onclick in propeties not acepting input

Tags: android, onclick

When I try to put a name or word for my onClick in the Andriod Studio properties, it does not accept it, all it does is greys it out and after pressing enter the name is not there.

I can put the onClick in the activitys_main.xml with no problem.

You can see from the picture I tried to enter it but it's just grey and not accepted.

Any idea why this would happen?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyV7J.png)

Comment: Have you set your context in the layout file? I mean, what activity is using that layout?

Answer (score 0):

better directly add it to ur xml

```
 android:onClick="method_name"
```